# appending single quotes in java prepared statements

Tags: java, spring-boot, prepared-statement, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have the following prepared statement.

```
"select * from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY where INSURANCE_ID = ? and SYS_CD = ? and ACCT_TYPE in (?)";
```

how can i append single quote before and after ?
for eg after passing params to the query, it should be like

```
"select * from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY where INSURANCE_ID = '1234' and SYS_CD = 'AA' and ACCT_TYPE in 'SDF'";
```

Comment: You don't add single quotes for placeholders in prepared statements, they get added automatically when needed (e.g for varchar, date types ..).

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to do it yourself, this is done either client-side by the JDBC driver or server-side by the database instance. Take a look at [How does the MySQL JDBC driver handle prepared statements](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-the-mysql-jdbc-driver-handle-prepared-statements/) article to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Adding backslash would help. 
`\'?\'`